# Compare history effective closest to transaction date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, history, audit

I am attempting to perform an audit compare the actual RATE for the day to the historical RATE that should have been paid on that day.

I have created a temp table to get the information needed from history and called this PPDAUDIT. Here is the audit SQL

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE, PAY_SUM_GRP, HOURS, RATE, TR_DATE, DATE, CORRECT_RATE
FROM 
( 
SELECT  A.EMPLOYEE 
    , A.PAY_SUM_GRP
    , A.HOURS
    , A.RATE
    , A.TR_DATE
    , A.DATE 
    , CASE
        WHEN (MAX((B.BEG_DATE) < A.TR_DATE))
        AND B.FLD_NBR = '730'
        THEN B.N_VALUE/C.ANNUAL_HOURS
    END AS 'CORRECT_RATE'
FROM `PPDAUDIT` AS A 
    INNER JOIN `[dbo]_[hrhistory]`    AS B ON B.EMPLOYEE = A.EMPLOYEE
INNER JOIN `[dbo]_[employee]`     AS C ON C.EMPLOYEE = A.EMPLOYEE
WHERE A.RATE <> (B.N_VALUE/C.ANNUAL_HOURS) 
) AS D
WHERE CORRECT_RATE IS NOT NULL
```

What I expected to get was the historical record less then but closest to the date of the transaction and then only get those were the history and transition didn't match. What it pulled was the second closest.

Example: If a transaction occurred on 1/1/2012 and there is history at 12/31/2011, 10/10/2011, and 7/24/2011 it pulls the rate attached to history on 10/10 rather than the 12/31 that is needed.

Comment: Which database are you using?  (SqlServer/MySQL/Oracle/...)

Comment: And which version?  (.../2005/2008/2012)

Comment: I should add that I have also attempted this in our MySQL database which is really just our play around with database that is a copy of production data. I ran accross the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2008, you can use `outer apply` to search for the latest history record.  For example, this searches for the last rate before the transaction date:

```
select  *
from    TransactionUnderInvestigation tui
outer apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    RateHistory rh
        where   rh.EmployeeId = tui.EmployeeId
                and RateStartDate <= tui.TransactionDate
        order by
                RateStartDate desc
        ) hist
```